# Show that the following product equals 1 (involves trig)

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, products

How can I show that:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left ( 1+2\cos\frac{2\pi .3^{k}}{3^{n}+1} \right )=1$$
Could you please explain to me how to approach this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: $\sin 3t=3\sin t-4\sin^3t=\sin t(3-4\sin^2t)=\sin t\{3-2(1-\cos 2t)\}=\sin t(1+2\cos2t)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

$$1+2 \cos{\theta} = \frac{\sin{(3 \theta/2)}}{\sin{(\theta/2})}$$

I get as a result for the product:

$$\frac{\sin{\left ( \frac{\pi \cdot 3^{n}}{3^n+1}\right)}}{\sin{\left( \frac{\pi}{3^n+1}\right)}} = 1$$

The way to get this result is to let $\theta_0 = 2 \pi/(3^n+1)$.  The product is then

$$\frac{\sin{(3 \theta_0/2)}}{\sin{(\theta_0/2)}} \frac{\sin{(3^2 \theta_0/2)}}{\sin{(3 \theta_0/2)}} \cdots \frac{\sin{(3^n \theta_0/2)}}{\sin{(3^{n-1} \theta_0/2)}}$$

The product telescopes, so we are left with just the last term in the numerator and the first term in the denominator.  The result follows.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please explain to me why you would start with $\sin3\theta$? I want to improve my problem solving skills but at the moment I don't know what to do when I see a question like this, I don't even know where to start. If I am given a hint I would most likely be able to do it but in the exam there are no hints :(

Comment: I wanted to manipulate the product so we'd get a bunch of stuff that canceled.  So I used the double-angle formulas $2 \cos{t} = \sin{2 t}/\sin{t}$, and then manipulated things until I saw how things would telescope.  I hate to say this, but the way to improve your problem-solving skills is to recognize patterns like the trig identities embedded in the problem statements.  I have no other advice than to understand these patterns and the various forms they might take.

Comment: @RonGordon, could you please explain how have reached at the product?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I think he substitutes $\theta=\cdots$

Comment: @RonGordon So I have to solve problems all day to be able to recognize the patterns :(

Comment: @AlexanderJones: in other words, you have to practice.